# Freebase: Is it possible to download a particular Type of data from freebase using API?

Tags: freebase

Let's say I need to download all the data related to /medicine/drugs and  from Freebase to store in my own database. Can I do so using the API ?

I found about their RDF dumps but they are quite huge. I only need a segment of that. How can that be done efficiently using the API ?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the API isn't really intended for bulk downloads.  There are about [8,974 drugs](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread/?lang=%2Flang%2Fen&query=%5B%7B%20%22type%22%3A%20%22%2Fmedicine%2Fdrug%22%2C%20%22return%22%3A%20%22count%22%20%7D%5D) in Freebase, so it's not completely infeasible.  You could probably start with something like [this query](https://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?lang=%2Flang%2Fen&q=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22%2Fmedicine%2Fdrug%22%2C%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22name%22%3Anull%2C%22*%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D):

```
[{
  "type": "/medicine/drug",
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "*": {
  }
}]
```

and embellish to suit your needs.  In particular, you'll probably need to use a cursor and add cursor handling support to your query application.

Alternatively, you could get a list of IDs with the MQLread API and then query them using the Topic API, e.g. [/en/aspirin](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/aspirin)

Lastly, a lot of the Freebase information came from FDA data sets such as the [Structured Product Labels](http://www.fda.gov/ForIndustry/DataStandards/StructuredProductLabeling/default.htm), so you might consider just downloading the relevant data sets directly from the FDA and using them.  That has the additional advantage that they'll stay up-to-date over time, unlike Freebase which has been frozen for over 6 months and will never be updated again.